# How to map proxy to NAT internet connection?

Tags: linux, proxy, socks, mapping

I have:

- Internet connection with proxy (SOCKS5) server.
- User's computers with MS Windows. These users don't want to use proxy, they want NAT/Masquerade internet.
- One linux box in this network.

How can I make "Proxy to socks" retranslator with it? Something, which will capture all "local" network request and map them into proxy requests?

Is there any software, designed for this purpose? Maybe some libraries I can utilize

Comment: Is there a reason you can't NAT them at your router?

Comment: I can. But ISP's rules are "any internet connection is through proxy", and this is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to tunnel all local network traffic to the socks proxy you can use [tun2socks](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/tun2socks).

Comment: Thank you. Description says it's exactly what I need. I'll try and report here.